# How to let each array index have a struct instance

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have a 2-dimensional 5x5 array in Swift. I am trying to have each array item to present a struct that has properties like cost and heuristics. for example, the  `grid[0][0]` item should have cost and heuristics values.

Swift implementation:

```
struct Spot {
    var cost: Int  // cost
    var heu: Int  // heuristics
}

var grid = [[Int]]
```

In Javascript I used to do it as:

```
function Spot() {
  this.cost = 0;
  this.heu = 0;
}

//This is what I'm looking for something equivalent in Swift
grid[0][0] = new Spot();
```

Sorry if this seems very basic, but I'm a beginner in Swift.

Comment: Depending on what exactly `Spot` is (its name, and the names of its members don't really communicate much), you probably want an `[[Int?]]`, with `nil`s marking the empty spots, rather than `Spot` instances with 0 cost and 0 "heu"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an array of `Spot` arrays `[[Spot]]`, not an array of `Int` arrays `[[Int]]`.

```
struct Spot {
    let cost: Int  // cost
    let heu: Int  // heuristics
}
```

---

```
var grid: [[Spot]] = .init(repeating: .init(repeating: .init(cost: 0, heu: 0), count: 5), count: 5)

grid[0][0] = .init(cost: 10, heu: 5)

print(grid)  // "[[Spot(cost: 10, heu: 5),...
print(grid[0][0].cost)   // 10
print(grid[0][0].heu)    // 5
```